# How can I get my active nav menu links working when I scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to set a navigation link to active using JavaScript when I scroll to specific sections in a web page.

I've tried making this code work but it isn't and I don't understand why. Also, I tried to get help with some people but they didn't find what was wrong here.

I hope somebody will found the solution.

Here's my codepen : https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/dygGbWy

Thanks for the help !

```js
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('header .nav_container nav a');

window.onscroll = () => {
    sections.forEach(sec => {
        let top = window.scrollY;
        let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
        let height = sec.offsetHeight;
        let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

        if(top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
            navLinks.forEach(links => {
                links.classList.remove('active');
                document.querySelector('header .nav_container nav a [href*=' + id + ']').classList.add ('active');
            })
        }
    })
};
```

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: pink;
}

header .nav_container{
    z-index: 8;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url(../img/background_nav.jpg);
}

header .nav_container nav{
    padding-top:32px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav a{
     color:#757575;
}

header .nav_container nav a{
    font-family: hagincaps;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:28px;
    text-decoration:none
}

header .nav_container nav a:hover, nav a.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #1B1B1B;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #1B1B1B;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="nav_container">
      <nav>
        <a href="#1" class="active">1</a>
        <a href="#2">2</a>
        <a href="#3">3</a>
        <a href="#4">4</a>
        <a href="#5">5</a>
      </nav>
  </header>
  
        <section id="1">
        <header>
            <h1>1</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="histoire_texte">
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

            <div><span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi! 

            <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

            <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.</p></span></div>
      
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <section id="2">
        <header>
            <h1>2</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="histoire_texte">
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

            <div><span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi! 

            <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

            <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.</p></span></div>
      
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <section id="3">
        <header>
            <h1>3</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="histoire_texte">
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

            <div><span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi! 

            <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

            <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.</p></span></div>
      
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <section id="4">
        <header>
            <h1>4</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="histoire_texte">
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

            <div><span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi! 

            <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

            <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.</p></span></div>
      
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <section id="5">
        <header>
            <h1>5</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="histoire_texte">
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

            <div><span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi! 

            <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

            <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.</p></span></div>
      
            <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

The smallest number of fixes needed to get your code working is within the `navLinks.forEach` loop. Your original code:

```
navLinks.forEach(links => {
    links.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('header .nav_container nav a [href*=' + id + ']').classList.add('active');
});
```

Executing a query selector on the `document` is unnecessary to search for the specific nav link with a `href` containing the `id` value.

Setting a reference to the element that's the container for the navigation anchor elements can be used for two purposes: 1. Removing any child elements with the 'active' class name; 2. Searching only within the container and returning the child element with a `href` containing the value of the `id` variable.

Based on the use of the container element, the code segment above is modified to the following. Note the use of the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with backticks to insert the value of the `id` variable into the attribute selector.

```
mobileNav.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove("active");
});
const navLink = mobileNav.querySelector(`[href*='#${id}']`);
if (navLink) { navLink.classList.add('active'); }
```

where the variable `mobileNav` is defined as:

```
let mobileNav = document.querySelector('header .nav_container nav');
```

The working solution:

```js
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let mobileNav = document.querySelector('header .nav_container nav');

window.onscroll = () => {
  sections.forEach(sec => {
    let top = window.scrollY;
    let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
    let height = sec.offsetHeight;
    let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

    if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
      mobileNav.querySelectorAll(".active").forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove("active");
      });
      const navLink = mobileNav.querySelector(`[href*='#${id}']`);
      if (navLink) {
        navLink.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: pink;
}

header .nav_container {
  z-index: 8;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(../img/background_nav.jpg);
}

header .nav_container nav {
  padding-top: 32px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav a {
  color: #757575;
}

header .nav_container nav a {
  font-family: hagincaps;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none
}

header .nav_container nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1B1B1B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #1B1B1B;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav_container">
    <nav>
      <a href="#1" class="active">1</a>
      <a href="#2">2</a>
      <a href="#3">3</a>
      <a href="#4">4</a>
      <a href="#5">5</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="1">
  <header>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="2">
  <header>
    <h1>2</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="3">
  <header>
    <h1>3</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="4">
  <header>
    <h1>4</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="5">
  <header>
    <h1>5</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Optimizations**

The code snippet above addresses the objective outlined in the original post with minimal changes. The code snippet below adds more code changes for optimizations. Comments in the code identify what they are.

```js
// Variable declarations were changed to 'const' from 'let'
// since variables are unchanged after declaration.
// Reference: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75
// `const` is a signal that the identifier won’t be reassigned.
// `let` is a signal that the variable may be reassigned.

const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const mobileNav = document.querySelector('header .nav_container nav');

window.onscroll = () => {
  // This value needs to be retrieved only once before
  // entering the 'for' loop.
  const top = window.scrollY;

  // Iterate sections list until one is set to active
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    const sec = sections[i];
    const offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
    const height = sec.offsetHeight;

    if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
      // Remove the 'active' class name from first element that
      // contains 'active' in its class list. There should be 
      // only one element that is active at a time.
      const curActive = mobileNav.querySelector(".active");
      if (curActive) {
        curActive.classList.remove("active");
      }

      // Add the 'active' class name to the navigation link.
      // The section ID is used only when inside of
      // the 'if' condition above.
      const navLink = mobileNav.querySelector(`[href*='#${sec.id}']`);
      if (navLink) {
        navLink.classList.add('active');
      }

      // There's no need to check the remaining sections
      // in the 'sections' list as 'sections[i]' is set to
      // active and only section can be set to active at
      // a time. Therefore, exit the scroll event listener
      // function.
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: pink;
}

header .nav_container {
  z-index: 8;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(../img/background_nav.jpg);
}

header .nav_container nav {
  padding-top: 32px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav a {
  color: #757575;
}

header .nav_container nav a {
  font-family: hagincaps;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none
}

header .nav_container nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1B1B1B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #1B1B1B;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav_container">
    <nav>
      <a href="#1" class="active">1</a>
      <a href="#2">2</a>
      <a href="#3">3</a>
      <a href="#4">4</a>
      <a href="#5">5</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="1">
  <header>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="2">
  <header>
    <h1>2</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="3">
  <header>
    <h1>3</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="4">
  <header>
    <h1>4</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="5">
  <header>
    <h1>5</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="histoire_texte">
    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>

    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptate harum saepe ipsam recusandae beatae delectus sunt, modi quae animi!

        <br><br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat rem quos delectus itaque aliquid facilis amet quasi non, illo necessitatibus!

        <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div><span><img src=""></span></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Intersection Observer API and debounce**

Further optimizations that are beyond the scope of the original post:

1. The use of the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) instead of the scroll event listener (the scroll event fires when the user clicks on a navigation link even though the scroll listener function is not needed).
2. Using a [debounce](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example) function to reduce the number of times the scroll event listener is fired while the user is scrolling.

Comment: hey thanks. So this just works now on my codepen but If I use the solution with the entire content of my website, it disapears once I scroll..

Comment: @Softee Great. Your original code was close. Can you fix the typo in `section.forEach` in your question as the code fixes/modifications were required in the `navLinks.forEach` loop? Also, can you clarify what "it" references in "it disappears once I scroll"?

Comment: @DaveB How do I do that please? here's my second codepen with your solution and the problem I'm talking about. As you can see once you're on the page under "TEASER" you'll see the underline, then if you scroll it disappears and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @DaveB https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/poxgZGz

Comment: @Softee I edited your original post by correcting the typo and reworded the first sentence to better identify the goal of your code. I updated the code snippet to work with your second codepen. I went back to the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors#substring_matching_selectors) you used in your question. That was the right approach and not what I used in my initial code snippet. Also, note the modification of the variable `navLinks` to `mobileNav`.

Comment: Great answer so far! Thanks for bringing IntersectionObserver here BTW.